# in_array or equal to 'x'

Tags: php

How can I check if a user belongs to a group in an array or their username ($un) is equal to 'X'. (failing that, I guess I could make it 2 separate checks)

I have the following but it gives me an 'unexpected OR' error:

```
<?php if (in_array('SMT', $adGroups)) or ($un == 'abc' || $un == 'xyz') echo 'blah'; ?>
```

Thanks ..

Comment: You get a parse error because you just cannot do `if(foo) or bar()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax of your code is wrong, you have an extra closing bracket `)`.

Try fixing it like this:

```
if (in_array('SMT', $adGroups) || $un == 'abc' || $un == 'xyz')  {
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Sorted! Thanks, Uby. You're a star :)

Answer (score 1):

Move the second closing parenthesis to the end of your condition:

```
if (in_array('SMT', $adGroups) or ($un == 'abc' || $un == 'xyz')) echo 'blah';
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a syntax error:

```
if (in_array('SMT', $adGroups)) or ($un == 'abc' || $un == 'xyz')...
                               ^
```

When an error message says "unexpected OR" it actually means what it says...

Comment: lol .. i figured that out, hence the post. The question was how do I fix it. Fixed now, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

A refined step is `if (in_array("SMT", $adGroups, true) || in_array($un, ["abc", "xyz"], true)) { print "blah"; }`, that would give you the ability of specifying as many different users as you want in your user check part. Avoid multiple `if()` statements and it solves the check faster.

Answer (score 0):

You have the closing parentheses in a wrong place. Try:

```
if (in_array('SMT', $adGroups) or ($un == 'abc' || $un == 'xyz')) echo 'blah';
```